# How to calculate Attack Bonus as a 5th Level Monk

Tags: dnd-5e, attack

Starting out at 5th level, and I am not sure how to calculate attack bonus.  The reason I have this question is because with the Martial Arts class feature it says that I would use DEX instead of STR for attack and damage rolls: do I use DEX when calculating my attack bonus, or, do I still use STR for calculating my attack bonus (for an unarmed strike)?

Strength is 11, so the STR modifier is 0 whereas Dexterity is 18, so the DEX modifier is 4.  Proficiency bonus is 3.

So would my unarmed attack bonus be 3 or 7?  Or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 19):

## Your attack bonus is +7.

The Martial Arts feature states:

> You can use Dexterity instead of Strength for the **attack and damage rolls** of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.

(emphasis mine)

Attack rolls determine if you hit, and damage rolls determine how much damage a hit deals.
The Martial Arts feature applies to both.

It is optional, but there is rarely any reason to choose the lower ability.

**attack roll**
d20 + ability modifier + proficiency bonus
d20 + 4 + 3

**damage roll**
damage dice + ability modifier
d6 + 4

Thus, you have a +7 bonus to attack rolls, and a +4 bonus to damage rolls with your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.